# How can I make authenticated request to django view from external html using ajax

Tags: python, ajax, django, html, django-authentication

I am using django 1.10, I have following html pages register.html, login.html, home.html

Html pages are deployed on different application server. I am using Custom user model,
I can able to register and store details into database. Also able to authenticate and login into app and get redirected to home page.

Problem :
I have sample view named as, test

```
 #viwes.py
    @login_required
    def test(request):
        l=[]
        l.append('x')
        l.append('y')
        return JsonResponse({"records": l})
```

so after login, when I directly access url as,

```
localhost:8000/app/test
```

then I am able to get data in browser.
But after login, within same session, when I am calling same url from home.html, I am not able to authenticate and receive data. 
In browser console it will become as,

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/app/test/
```

There were some posts which refers solution as @ajax_required, as I am new to django, I didn't find any post in detail. Can anyone please explain or suggest solution with sample example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to send `csrf` token in ajax call payload to identify user.

Comment: Thanks vinay kumar. Can you give example of it or redirect to it.

Comment: Dou you host your html with ajax on same server as Django app?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with below code and working file

## views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http.response import JsonResponse
from django.views.generic.base import View

class LoginRequiredMixin(object):
    @classmethod
    def as_view(cls, **initkwargs):
        view = super(LoginRequiredMixin, cls).as_view(**initkwargs)
        return login_required(view)


class TestLogin(LoginRequiredMixin, View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        l = []
        l.append('x')
        l.append('y')
        return JsonResponse({"records": l})
```

## urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

from myapp.views import TestLogin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^test/$', TestLogin.as_view(), name='testview'),
]
```

## Curl

```
curl -X GET -H "Cookie: csrftoken=t1l5CpH7kL5J48yf0c4C0z9kli3UfI3enCEdT4lH8RGQip1y8f8t1l3ucDWWzRGX,sessionid=99oqphuhy1udboq4pv2icgj408b1lpxi" "http://localhost:8000/test/"
```

Comment: can't we just use @login_required decorator on view function instead of using LoginRequiredMixin class.

Comment: If you're using class base view then `@method_decorator(login_required)` will be fine..

Comment: I am using function based views. So does it work for view as per mentioned in my question?